# Jira Groovy Script SQL SP or function not return

Tags: sql, groovy, jira, jira-rest-java-api

SQL SP running smoothly. But Groovy Script SQL connection SP return error and return=null

Groovy Code:

```
private String get_sube_kodu_bul(String subeAdi) {
    MutableIssue mutableIssue = issue
    def wasIndexing = ImportUtils.indexIssues
    ImportUtils.indexIssues = true
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.xx.xx.xxx:1433/DBNAME", "UsrName","Pass", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
    subeAdi = subeAdi.trim()
    def row = sql.firstRow("EXEC SP '${subeAdi}'")
    return row.SUBE_KODU
}
```

Log Error:

```
The script failed : java.sql.SQLException: 
    The executeQuery method must return a result set.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you'll show us the code :)

Comment: Hi Pawel, Edited message :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`firstRow()` expects to have result set as return value of executed statement. It seems that your stored procedure returns only one value (SUBE_KODU). According to [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) you should use rather `call()`. Something like below should do the job:

```
private String get_sube_kodu_bul(String subeAdi) {
    MutableIssue mutableIssue = issue
    def wasIndexing = ImportUtils.indexIssues
    ImportUtils.indexIssues = true
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.xx.xx.xxx:1433/DBNAME", "UsrName","Pass", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
    subeAdi = subeAdi.trim()
    def subeKodu
    sql.call("EXEC SP '${subeAdi}'", { returnedSubeKodu -> subeKodu = returnedSubeKodu })
    return subeKodu
}
```